# Select sum until a set amount and then update fields in mysql database

Tags: mysql, sql, sum, sql-update, aggregate-functions

```
 item_id      rate            status
 ---------    -----------     ------
   1           12              credit
   2           10              credit
   3           10              credit
   4           20              cash
   5           55              credit
```

I have the above table, A user inputs and amount of 25. Now I want to update the status of the rows having credit as status from credit to cash until the sum of rate is 25, so in the above table the top 1 rows having a sum of 22 should get a status of cash. Since the user input is 25, I still have a balance of 3 (25-22), this balance should be deducted from the third row making the third row rate 7. The result I want is tabular form with the changes highlighted:

```
 item_id      rate            status
 ---------    -----------     ------
   1           12              **cash**
   2           10              **cash**
   3           **7**           credit
   4           20              cash
   5           55              credit
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use window functions to identify the rows that need to be changed:

```
select item_id, 
    case when sum_rate >= 25 then 'credit' else 'cash' end as status, 
    case when sum_rate >= 25 then sum_rate - 25 else rate end as rate
from (
    select t.*, sum(rate) over(order by item_id) sum_rate
    from mytable t
    where status = 'credit'
) t
where sum_rate - rate < 25
```

You can put that logic in an `update` statement if you prefer:

```
update mytable t
inner join (
    select item_id, sum(rate) over(order by item_id) sum_rate
    from mytable t
    where status = 'credit'
) t1 on t1.item_id = t.item_id
set 
    t.status = case when sum_rate >=  25 then 'credit' else 'cash' end,
    t.rate =   case when t1.sum_rate >= 25 then t1.sum_rate - 25 else t.rate end
where t1.sum_rate - t.rate < 25
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=234d349a7205443a23a88de11bb531b4)**

Comment: hello, thanks but when I try to update using the code the rate is not correct and it changes the status of the row rate is changed too, which should not be the case

Comment: @HamzaZahir: I just did a small update to the answer (but it does not change the rate). This does produce the result that you have shown for your sample data, so I don't know what you mean by *not correct*.

Comment: When I tried with one value as user input it was correct but when I tried with another value as user input and the resulting rate was not correct.

Comment: @HamzaZahir: this is too vague. Please edit the fiddle to show what you think is not working properly.

Comment: could you please check the fiddle now? the expected result is status of id 2 should be changed to cash and rate of id 3 should be 9 (11-10  where 11 is the input value and 10 is the rate of id 2), not necessarily id 3 to be rate changed, id 1 rate also can be changed.

Comment: @HamzaZahir: please share the new fiddle link (the link changes every time it is updated).

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d309563b8395b60d48cfec424fbeb76f

Comment: @HamzaZahir: you gave a target of 11 and the first row has 12, so only this row is updated.

Comment: ok thanks, your solution is working perfect and the only problem is the status gets changed on the row we change rate, the row  that gets rate changed should retain it's initial status and should not be changed.

Comment: @HamzaZahir: again, what the query does in that regard is consistent with your sample data / results. Look closely at the fiddle.

Comment: thank you, I have accepted your answer and posted the status issue as a new question please check it here  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65147004/select-sum-until-certain-amount-and-then-update-certain-fields-based-on-conditio