# select sum until certain amount and then update certain fields based on condition

Tags: mysql

I have a query that changes the status of some fields and rate of another field.

[fiddle expample](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2e0238d0849dd412baaf6a72fb6eb9df)

```
CREATE TABLE mytable(
   item_id INTEGER  NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY 
  ,rate    INTEGER  NOT NULL
  ,status  VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO mytable(item_id,rate,status) VALUES (1,12,'credit');
INSERT INTO mytable(item_id,rate,status) VALUES (2,10,'credit');
INSERT INTO mytable(item_id,rate,status) VALUES (3,10,'credit');
INSERT INTO mytable(item_id,rate,status) VALUES (4,20,'cash');
INSERT INTO mytable(item_id,rate,status) VALUES (5,55,'credit');

select item_id, 'cash' as status, 
    case when sum_rate >= 23 then sum_rate - 23 else rate end as rate
from (
    select t.*, sum(rate) over(order by item_id) sum_rate
    from mytable t
    where status = 'credit'
) t
where sum_rate - rate < 23;


update mytable t
inner join (
    select item_id, sum(rate) over(order by item_id) sum_rate
    from mytable t
    where status = 'credit'
) t1 on t1.item_id = t.item_id
set 
    t.status = 'cash',
    t.rate = case when t1.sum_rate >= 23 then t1.sum_rate - 23 else t.rate end
where t1.sum_rate - t.rate < 23
```

The logic checks the sum of all rows until a value of 23 is reached and changes the status of those rows to `cash`, in the example since the total of `rate` in top 3 rows is greater than 23, the third row is updated with the balance after adding the first two rows. I want the third row `status` to remain the same and only the `rate` to be updated.

The problem the above code is that it updates all the `status` of all rows having sum of `rate` 23.

[The original question for reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65135819/select-sum-until-a-set-amount-and-then-update-fields-in-mysql-database/65135945?noredirect=1#comment115156175_65135945)

Comment: It seems like you're using SO to write all your code for you. First someone wrote the original code in the previous question, now you want someone else to fix it for you. You need to make your own attempt first.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I was able to get it done with the following addition to the query so posting it in case it may help anyone with a similar requirement.

```
t.status = case when t1.sum_rate >= 23 then 'credit'  else 'cash' end
```